# Auto click button in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {    
    var esta = 0;

    function cambiar(){
        if ($esta == 0) {
            $(".inerr a.next").click();
            $esta = 1;
        }
        else if ($esta == 1){
            $(".inerr a.prev").click();
            $esta = 0;
        }
    }

    setInterval(cambiar, 5000);
});

</script>
```

I´m trying to click the a.next or a.prev every 5 secs, for an image change. But i can´t. What is wrong with this?

Comment: You have a variable named `esta` and one named `$esta`, are those supposed to be the same thing?

Comment: yes, that is supposed to be the same variable

Comment: Well... that's the issue at hand here. You are getting an error the first time `cambiar` runs. Watching your JS console is really helpful when debugging.

Answer (score 1):

You instantiate the variable `esta`
and then checks the variable `$esta`

try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {    
        var $esta = 0;

        function cambiar(){
            if ($esta == 0) {
                $(".inerr a.next").click();
                $esta = 1;
            }
            else if ($esta == 1){
                $(".inerr a.prev").click();
                $esta = 0;
            }
        }

        setInterval(cambiar, 5000);
    });

    </script>
```